# How to change accept header at google chrome?

Tags: php, header, xhtml, mime-types

I want to see an error which will happen if I send not valid(according to XHTML standard) markup to browser. I'm using `google chrome` as browser, `apache` as server and `php` as script language. I've created a script with such lines:

```
header('Content-type:  application/xhtml+xml');

$content = <<< XHTML
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>XHTML</title>
 </head>
 <BODY>
   <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</P>
 </BODY>
</html>
XHTML;

echo $content;
```

It should be incorrect because of `BODY` from capital letters.
But I'm getting correct results, because I see that `google chrome` accept such mime-types:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

So it interprets result as `text/html` and everything is fine.

I want to make this document invalid. How I can remove `text/html` from accepted headers at `google chrome`? Or I am wrong at something?

**UPD**
When I removed closing `BODY` tag, I can see an error. Seems that browser don't care about such little mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misdiagnosing the problem.

- The accept header tells the server that HTML and XHTML are equally preferred.
- Your script *ignores* the accept header entirely and sends an XHTML content type
- XML parsers will not throw parsing errors on well-formed documents, even if they are invalid
- Current browsers (as far as I know, I haven't experimented with this in a while) will fall back to an HTML parser if they get non-well-formed XHTML (because telling end users that page authors made a type is, 99/100 times, unhelpful).

If you want to detect validity errors, then use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) (which is a tool designed to detect them) and not a browser (which is a tool designed to render web pages and recover from author errors).

Answer (score 0):

> So it interprets result as text/html and everything is fine.
>
> I want to make this document invalid. How I can remove text/html from accepted headers at google chrome? Or I am wrong at something?

Although the browser will send several content types in the `Accept` header, the server is open to choose one of them in the response.

This is done by setting the `Content-Type` header in the response (As you do)

```
header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml');
```

This tells the browser that response is an XHTML document. You have no further chances to influence the browsers validation process.

Seems that chrome is too much forgiving and accepts the uppercased `<BODY>`.